# How to fix MultiValueDictKeyError in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

This is my form

```
<h1>ADD LIST</h1>
        <form action="addList/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class = "container">
                <label>List Name</label><br>
                <input  name="listname" class= "listNamec"><br><br></input>
                <label>List title</label><br>
                <input name="listtitle"  class= "listTitlec"><br><br></input>  
            </div>
        </form>
```

And this my function

```
def addList(response):

    listname = response.POST['listname']

    list.name = listname
    list.save()

    return render(response, 'main/index.html', {})
```

error :

```
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'listname'
```

i need to add these to Todolist database, and not workin :(

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this error occurs when you're trying to [access a key that does not exist](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0dd29209091280ccf34e07c9468746c396b7778e/django/utils/datastructures.py#L78-L90) in `MultiValueDict`. You need to verify first that the key exists before getting it's value:

```py
# using the `in` keyword
if "listname" in request.POST:
    listname = response.POST["listname"]


# or using the `get` method
listname = request.POST.get("listname", False)
if listname:
    ...
```

Make sure to return an error when the key does not exist. Also, since you've encountered this, verify that you're actually passing the form data to the route properly. Make sure to read the django documents and understand how forms are being handled.